# Multiple BarPlot at same point

Tags: ios, objective-c, bar-chart

I am developing a application.In the application i need bar graph .Please see the see below image [image: in image we are showing multiple plots at a point]

I want to develop such type of bar graph .i have done a lot of R&D but not find solution.Please Help me

Thanks 
Dheerendra singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot? I used this once and was happy with its API.
By the way: why do you need multiple plots? The plot in your screenshot seems to be made of continuous data...

Comment: ye i am using this API but not able to find solution like added image

Answer (score 0):

[Core plot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is best available Graph lib for achieving this kinda bar but you have to do some customisation by your self.